# Error java.lang.AbstractMethodError when start a new compose project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I working on android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1 and getting this error when I create a compose project

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver.onCreate(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)"
    at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:36)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:808)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:22010)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4291)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4298)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4298)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4298)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4298)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3135)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2618)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9971)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1010)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:809)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:744)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:995)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

the error occurs when I run the project.

I tried to change `ComponentActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` but same error happing

---

**UPDATE**

problem solved by upgrading gradle version to v7.1.1

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194289155

Comment: problem solved by upgrading gradle version to v7.1.1

Comment: Still seeing this issue on 7.2.2 wen building a project with an AAR.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gabriele Mariotti already commented, Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0-alpha04 breaks the starting of Compose apps from Android Studio. You can workaround it by setting you apps Min SDK version to 24 or by installing your Compose app by commandline to your device and starting it there.

Or you can downgrade AGP to 7.1.0-alpha03 but then you will also have to downgrade to Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Canary 3 as well.

Comment: problem solved by upgrading gradle version to v7.1.1